Implementing Foldable for an n-ary tree in Haskell with inorder traversal
I'm trying to implement the Foldable instance for an n-ary tree data structure in Haskell. I want to define foldr such that it traverses the tree in inorder. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly.
Here's my code:
data TreeL a = NodeL a [TreeL a] deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable TreeL where
  foldr f b (NodeL x []) = f x b
  foldr f b (NodeL x (t:ts)) = foldr f (foldr f b ts)


I have a test property prop_tree_foldable that checks if the fold is done correctly and in order.  It generates a random tree and checks if the result of foldr (:) [] (fst <$> t) is a sorted list of numbers. However, my implementation is failing this test.
I've tried a few different approaches, but I can't seem to get the traversal order right. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Wait, what's in-order for that type? I don't think that's even defined for 1 element and no children per node.

Err, n children per node.

The code you've provided can't fail any tests, because it doesn't compile.

What is in-order of there is one child, or three children? Where do you generate the value for the node?

Concretely, what's the in-order traversal of NodeL 1 [NodeL 2 [], NodeL 3 [], NodeL 4 []]? Is it [2, 1, 3, 4], or [2, 3, 1, 4], or  possibly even [2, 1, 3, 1, 4]?

You say the test generates a random tree. From which distribution is this drawn? The obvious distributions do not produce trees which can possibly validate the property isSorted (foldr (:) [] (fst <$> t)), no matter what implementation of foldr you write.

I'm uncertain what the correct solution is, as I don't know what "in-order" means for that data type.
But I can tell you for sure that you're only generating a list of elements in leaf nodes. You're not doing anything with x in the recursive case. In fact, you're also throwing out t, so you aren't even seeing all leaf nodes. There's no way your solution can be correct if you aren't using the entire argument.
For what it's worth, it's far easier to write foldr in terms of toList for this data type. I'd strongly recommend starting there.

Implementing foldMap seems pretty easy (ignoring the confusing "inorder" constraint). Why go via toList, which isn't actually part of a minimal Foldable implementation?

@amalloy because for a beginner, toList is fewer concepts to wrap your head around. It's not what I'd do for a production quality library, but it's a reasonable way to get started.

For binary trees, it is accepted that in-order traversal means a traversal in Left-Root-Right order.
However, for TreeL traversals, with an unspecified number of child subtrees, it is not clear what in-order could mean.
The reasonable choices of traversal seem to be:

process the root value Before the child subtrees
process the root value After the child subtrees

Let's call the folding functions for these two choices foldrB and foldrA respectively.
We can use the list version of foldr to write the code for both options:
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.4.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
λ> data TreeL a = NodeL a [TreeL a]  deriving  (Show, Eq)
λ> 
λ> foldrA f acc0 (NodeL x ts) = f x  (foldr (\t acc -> foldrA f acc t) acc0 ts)
λ> 
λ> foldrB f acc0 (NodeL x ts) = foldr  (\t acc -> foldrB f acc t)   (f x acc0)  ts
λ> 

It turns out that flattening the tree into a plain list, using the usual method of foldr (:) [], gives a more intuitive result when using foldrA:
λ> 
λ> instance Foldable TreeL  where  foldr = foldrA
λ> 
λ> lf0 = NodeL (10::Int) []
λ> lf1 = NodeL (11::Int) []
λ> lf2 = NodeL (12::Int) []
λ> tr1 = NodeL (21::Int) [lf0, lf1]
λ> tr2 = NodeL (42::Int) [tr1,lf2]
λ> 
λ> foldr (:) [] tr2
[42,21,10,11,12]
λ> 
λ> toListFromTreeL = foldrA (:) []
λ> :type toListFromTreeL
toListFromTreeL :: TreeL t1 -> [t1]
λ> 
λ> toListFromTreeL tr2
[42,21,10,11,12]
λ> 

That being said, there is nothing in the above code that could possibly make an ordered list from a randomly generated tree. That's for a sorting not a folding operation. We might be missing an essential piece of information regarding your prop_tree_foldable property.

Addendum:
It is actually possible to have the Haskell system provide the Foldable instance for TreeL automatically, using appropriate language extensions. One can proceed like this:
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.4.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
λ> 
λ> :set -XDeriveFoldable
λ> :set -XStandaloneDeriving 
λ> 
λ> data TreeL a = NodeL a [TreeL a]  deriving  (Show, Eq)
λ> 
λ> deriving instance Foldable TreeL
λ> 
... define tr2 as before ...
λ>
λ> foldr (:) [] tr2
[42,21,10,11,12]
λ> 

So FWIW the behavior of the « default » Foldable instance appears to be in agreement with foldrA.

data TreeL a = NodeL a [TreeL a] deriving (Show, Eq)
instance Foldable TreeL where
    foldr fn acc (NodeL a xs)  = fn a (foldr (flip (foldr fn)) acc xs) 
    foldMap fn (NodeL a xs)  = fn a <> (foldMap (foldMap fn) xs) 

This should work, it compiles for ghc. It should be self explanatory, but if you examine it you can see that (foldr fn) :: b -> Tree a -> b, so you can use the list version of foldr on that.
I just realized that jpmarinier did the exact same thing. The foldrA.
